# Incorrect Credentials: Windows Server Backup

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, login, windows-server-backup

I have three windows servers I'm trying to backup to a network folder. I was able to schedule a backup of the first two with no problem, but the third one (the domain controller) throws the error "The user name or password is incorrect." I am using the same login credentials as the other two computers.

I have tried logging on with the local domain, the domain, the computer name, and no computer name. If I don't get the login error, I get an error recognizing the username. I have tried giving everyone read/write permissions (for troubleshooting purposes) and that doesn't work either. I read [this](https://forums.veeam.com/veeam-agent-for-windows-f33/configure-backup-fails-with-wrong-user-name-or-password-t32610.html) forum post suggesting to make sure the clock is set up correctly, which it is.

I've tried rebooting the computer and when I did, I got this warning:[image]

Is there a troubleshooting step I'm missing? Is something improperly configured on the third computer preventing it from backing up?